# Want to retrieve Product ID and Affiliate Tag from Amazon url using php

Tags: php, regex

I Want to retrieve Product ID and Affiliate Tag from Amazon url usin php.
I tried using Preg_match but not getting clear result.
In below link: I want to retrieve Id ="B07NX7Q9NB" and tag=AffiliateTag.

[https://www.amazon.com/Crest-Pro-Health-Smooth-Formula-Toothpaste/dp/B07NX7Q9NB/ref=as_li_ss_tl?pf_rd_r=J44K1V7XYBW7TEKCTCMB&pf_rd_p=43ea9b7e-4160-4f68-b311-3810df065596&pd_rd_r=d2245fd7-4cdf-4238-ae60-3b4165911324&pd_rd_w=cb1VP&pd_rd_wg=H8xUK&ref_=pd_gw_cr_cartx&linkCode=ll1&tag=AffiliateTag-20&linkId=0f486cc77ca6ae3e199f1fe07ecaf8f8&language=en_US](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NX7Q9NB)

Can someone help me with writing Preg_Match system.

Comment: What regex pattern did you use?

Comment: `if ( preg_match( '~(?:/|^)(?<ID>[^/]*)/[^/]*?[?&]tag=(?<Tag>[^/&]*)~', $input, $matches ) ) // $matches['ID'] and $matches['Tag'] contain info`

Answer (score 0):

A simple soultion would be:

```
$link = "https://www.amazon.com/Crest-Pro-Health-Smooth-Formula-Toothpaste/dp/B07NX7Q9NB/ref=as_li_ss_tl?pf_rd_r=J44K1V7XYBW7TEKCTCMB&pf_rd_p=43ea9b7e-4160-4f68-b311-3810df065596&pd_rd_r=d2245fd7-4cdf-4238-ae60-3b4165911324&pd_rd_w=cb1VP&pd_rd_wg=H8xUK&ref_=pd_gw_cr_cartx&linkCode=ll1&tag=AffiliateTag-20&linkId=0f486cc77ca6ae3e199f1fe07ecaf8f8&language=en_US";
```

Use `parse_str` to convert the parameters to array

```
parse_str($test, $outputArray);
$tag = $outputArray['tag'];

var_dump($tag);
```

Result:

`string(15) "AffiliateTag-20"`